# ¿Problema con validaciones en inputs dinamicos con ajax?

Tags: jquery

tengo un problema, tengo un codigo para generar inputs dinamicos que a su vez envia a una funcion en laravel para insertar varios registros a la vez en la base de datos.

Este es el codigo que genera los inputs

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var c = 100;
        $('#addCat').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

        var formularioCat =  '<div  class="form-group CategoriaDinamica" >';
            formularioCat+=         '<label for="categoria" class="col-md-4 control-label">Categoria '+c+'</label>';
            formularioCat+=          '<div class="col-md-6">';

            formularioCat+=              ' <input  class="form-control" name="categoriadinamica[]" type="text" value="">';                      
            formularioCat+=          ' </div>';                            
            formularioCat+=   ' </div>';   


            $(formularioCat).hide().insertBefore('#botonenvio').fadeIn(500);

            c++;

        })

        $('#removeCat').on('click',function(r){
            r.preventDefault();
            $('#botonenvio').prev().remove();


        })
```

Tengo este codigo para las futuras validaciones

```
this.addynotificacion = function(campoaiterar,nombrearray,estado,mensaje){
    $(campoaiterar).each(function(i) {
            nombrearray.push($(this).val());
                if(nombrearray[i]=='')
                    {
                         $('.jumbotron').before(notificacion(estado,mensaje));  

                        return false;
                    }   

        });


}
```

Y esta es la funcion ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bsubmit').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var rutaCompleta = 'http://localhost/ficheros/public/admin/categorias';

        var namecatdin = $('input[name="categoriadinamica[]"]');
        var datos = [];


                addynotificacion(
                namecatdin,
                datos,
                'danger',
                'NO PUEDES DEJAR UNA CATEGORIA EN BLANCO :: LAS SIGUIENTES NO SE INSERTARAN');

            $.ajax({
                    url: rutaCompleta,
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {'datosarray':datos},
                    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') },
                })
                .done(function(datosarray) {
                    console.log("success_creacion_"+$.type(datosarray));
                    var muchosdata = [];
                    addynotificacion(
                        namecatdin,
                        muchosdata,
                        'success',
                        'REGISTRO ..:: '+muchosdata[i]+' ::.. CREADO CORRECTAMENTE'
                        );          


                    })
                .fail(function(x) {
                    console.log(' nombre_error: '+x.errorThrown);
                })
                .always(function() {
                    console.log("complete");
                });

    })
});
```

El problema es que creo que no se me ocurre como meter la validacion, ya que en si fuese un solo input a introducir en la bbdd no habria problema pero con mas de uno me esta fallando, me hace la primera validacion bien y luego me inserta los registros en los siguientes, en este caso la validacion comprueba que el registro no este en blanco, pues el primer registro no lo introduce en la base de datos pero todos los siguientes los introduce como caracteres en blanco, la idea obviamene es meter mas validaciones, pero primero me tiene que funcionar con la primera y que evalue todos los registros y luego utilize la funcion ajax.

Luego como algo aparte

Esta funcion me da este error

```
this.addynotificacion = function(campoaiterar,nombrearray,estado,mensaje){
        $(campoaiterar).each(function(i) {
                nombrearray.push($(this).val());
                    if(nombrearray[i]=='')
                        {
                             $('.jumbotron').before(notificacion(estado,mensaje));  

                            return false;
                        }   

            });


    }
```

**ReferenceError: i is not defined**

¿Como puedo acomodarlo para usarlo correctamente en la otra funcion?

Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo a tu input tienes que colocarle una clase para recorrer. y el each aplicárselo a la misma. como por ejemplo:

```
$('.checked').each(function(){
     $(this).attr('id');
});
```

en la funcion que te coloco recorres todos los que tengan la clase "checked" y de cada una tomas ese objeto y puedes extraer el valor que desees. al tener el valor se lo puedes mandar a la funcion ajax uno por uno o puedes hacer un .push en un array para mandar el array completo.

intenta no colocar en la ruta la ruta completa. solo la ruta de la pagina que colocas en `Route::get('categorias');` recuerda que así evitas cambiar las rutas al pasar a producción o hacer cambios.

Espero te sirva de ayuda.